# Create multiple coupons programmatically in WooCommerce 3+

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, foreach, coupon

In wooCommerce, I am using the following code to create programmatically a single coupon:

```html
$coupon_amount = '20';
   $code_value    = wp_generate_password( 15, false );
   $coupon_code   = $code_value; 
   $expiry_date   = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+140 days'));

    function create_coupon_codes($coupon_amount, $coupon_code, $expiry_date, $email_address) {

          global $wpdb;
          $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = %s AND post_type = 'shop_coupon' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 1;", $coupon_code );
          $coupon_id = $wpdb->get_var( $sql );
          if ( empty( $coupon_id ) ) {

            $coupon = array(
                'post_title'   => $coupon_code,
                'post_content' => '',
                'post_status'  => 'publish',
                'post_author'  => 1,
                'post_type'    => 'shop_coupon'
            );
            $newcouponid = wp_insert_post( $coupon );

            update_post_meta( $newcouponid, 'product_ids', '' );
            update_post_meta( $newcouponid, 'exclude_product_ids', '' );
            update_post_meta( $newcouponid, 'discount_type', 'store_credit' );
            update_post_meta( $newcouponid, 'free_shipping', 'no' );
            update_post_meta( $newcouponid, 'coupon_amount', $coupon_amount );
            update_post_meta( $newcouponid, 'individual_use', 'yes' );
            update_post_meta( $newcouponid, 'expiry_date', $expiry_date ); 
            update_post_meta( $newcouponid, 'usage_limit', '1' );       
            update_post_meta( $newcouponid, 'apply_before_tax', 'yes' );
            update_post_meta( $newcouponid, 'customer_email', $email_address );
              
               }
            }

          create_coupon_codes($coupon_amount, $coupon_code, $expiry_date, $email_address);
```

It's working fine. As you can see, the coupon code (coupon name) is auto generated using [`wp_generate_password()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_password/) WordPress function.

Now I would like to create multiple coupons *(instead a single user)* with multiple discount amounts and multiple expiry dates and multiple coupon codes.

How can I create multiple coupons programmatically in WooCommerce with multiple discount amounts?

Answer (score 5):

Your code is not applying (or adding a coupon)… It's **"creating" a new coupon!**.

since WooCommerce 3, your code is a bit outdated. Instead you should better use the available [`WC_Coupon` **setter methods**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Coupon.html) like in the code below.

As you are generating the coupon code name with `wp_generate_password()` function, you need to check that the new generated coupon code doesn't exist yet, as WooCommerce requires that each coupons code name is unique *(see below a custom function for that purpose)*.

To generate `multiple` coupons, you can just make a **foreach loop** that will iterate through a **defined** array of coupons  **costs**.

1). First **a utility function to generate unique non existing coupon names** *(coupon codes)*:

```
// Utility function that generate a non existing coupon code (as each coupon code has to be unique)
function generate_coupon_code() {
    global $wpdb;
    
    // Get an array of all existing coupon codes
    $coupon_codes = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT post_name FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'shop_coupon'");
    
    for ( $i = 0; $i < 1; $i++ ) {
        $generated_code = strtolower( wp_generate_password( 15, false ) );
        
        // Check if the generated code doesn't exist yet
        if( in_array( $generated_code, $coupon_codes ) ) {
            $i--; // continue the loop and generate a new code
        } else {
            break; // stop the loop: The generated coupon code doesn't exist already
        }
    }
    return $generated_code;
}
```

Code goes in `functions.php` file of your active child theme (or active theme).

---

2). Now the code with the foreach loop [`WC_Coupon` **setter methods**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Coupon.html) to generate multiple coupons based on a defined array of coupon discount amounts *(replaced non existing 'store_credit' coupon type by 'fixed_cart')*:

```
// Here below define your coupons discount amount
$discount_amounts = array( 12, 18, 15, 10 );

// Set some coupon data by default
$date_expires     = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+371 days'));
$discount_type    = 'fixed_cart'; // 'store_credit' doesn't exist

// Loop through the defined array of coupon discount amounts
foreach( $discount_amounts as $coupon_amount ) {
    // Get an emty instance of the WC_Coupon Object
    $coupon = new WC_Coupon();
    
    // Generate a non existing coupon code name
    $coupon_code  = generate_coupon_code();

    // Set the necessary coupon data (since WC 3+)
    $coupon->set_code( $coupon_code );
    $coupon->set_discount_type( $discount_type );
    $coupon->set_amount( $coupon_amount );
    
    $coupon->set_date_expires( $date_expires );
    $coupon->set_usage_limit( 1 );
    $coupon->set_individual_use( true );

    // Create, publish and save coupon (data)
    $coupon->save();
}
```

Tested and works.

> **Notes:**
>
> - "expiry_date" property is replaced by "date_expires"
> - `apply_before_tax` property doesn't exist anymore
> - "free_shipping" is always set to `false` *(no)* by default